# Why does my function not output the last statement when the if condition inside the while loop turns out false?

Tags: c++, if-statement

```
void LinkedList::FindSum(int target){
    int a =0;
    Node* current = new Node;


    if(head != NULL)
    {
        current = head;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"The list is empty."<<endl;
    }


    while(current != NULL)
    {
        Node* find = current;
        a = target - current->data;
        while(find != NULL)
    {
        find = find->next;
        if(find->data == a)
        {
            cout <<"Yes there are 2 values that add to get the target."<<endl;
            cout << a <<endl;
            cout << current->data <<endl;   
            return;
        }
    }
       current = current->next;
   }


    cout << "The 2 values were not found."<<endl;

}
```

This is the following code for my function, when applied in main and it turns out to be false, it does not cout the last statement, and I have been unable to understand why.

Comment: [How to Debug Small Programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) is a very useful skill in programming.

Comment: Your indentation is misleading.

Comment: Obvisously, you never reach the last `cout`. At some point the `if` inside `while` gets `true` and returns.

Comment: @DimChtz hello thank you for your comment , but if this was true the program should have given a certain output but it did not. I think the Linked List class may have caused a problem.

Comment: @G.Chouchani "Linked List class may have caused a problem" If the problem is outside the code you provided, there is no way for us to tell.

Comment: @DimChtz I used the basic Linked List code, I thought about putting it in the question, but didn't want to overcrowd the question,

Comment: @Eljay Will do!, thanks for the recommendation and will work on providing more insightful or deeper thought questions to the society.

Comment: `Node* current = new Node;` is suspicious. If `head != nullptr` you leak the instance right away. There should be no reason for creating a new `Node` inf a `Find` function.  Are you sure you didn't mean to use `Node* current = nullptr` instead?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I wanted the current node to remain the same to be able to itterate it later, since i would need 2 nodes to iterate, this is to be able to find the sum of 2 numbers in a list, if they reach a certain target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The inner `while` loop is not written correctly.

```
while(current != NULL){
   Node* find = current;
   a = target - current->data;
   while(find != NULL){

      find = find->next;

      // PROBLEM
      // At some point find will be NULL. By dereferncing a NULL
      // pointer, your code enters into undefined behavior territory.
      if(find->data == a){
         cout <<"Yes there are 2 values that add to get the target."<<endl;
         cout << a <<endl;
         cout << current->data <<endl;   
         return;
      }
   }
   current = current->next;
}
```

I suggest changing that block of code to:

```
while(current != NULL){
   a = target - current->data;
   Node* find = current->next;
   while(find != NULL){
      if(find->data == a){
         cout <<"Yes there are 2 values that add to get the target."<<endl;
         cout << a <<endl;
         cout << current->data <<endl;   
         return;
      }
      find = find->next;
   }
   current = current->next;
}
```

My personal preference is to use a `for` loop.

```
for ( ; current != NULL; current = current->next )
{
   a = target - current->data;
   for ( Node* find = current->next; find != NULL; find = find->next )
   {
      if(find->data == a)
      {
         cout <<"Yes there are 2 values that add to get the target."<<endl;
         cout << a <<endl;
         cout << current->data <<endl;   
         return;
      }
   }
}
```

#### Suggestion for cleanup

Use of

```
Node* current = new Node;
```

causes memory leak. It is also incorrect when the list is empty. You don't need it. Here's a cleaned up version of the function.

```
void LinkedList::FindSum(int target){
   int a = 0;

   if(head == NULL)
   {
      cout<<"The list is empty."<<endl;
   }

   for ( Node* current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
   {
      a = target - current->data;
      for ( Node* find = current->next; find != NULL; find = find->next )
      {
         if(find->data == a)
         {
            cout <<"Yes there are 2 values that add to get the target."<<endl;
            cout << a <<endl;
            cout << current->data <<endl;   
            return;
         }
      }
   }

   cout << "The 2 values were not found."<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, brilliantly written and well said!

Comment: @G.Chouchani, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

You used **return** statement inside the **if- statement** . If your code returns something then after returning first time the code ends there and the codes after that return statement won't be executed.

Comment: True, but that will only happen if the if statement occurs (when the condition is true), my question is when the condition returns false, what happens.

Comment: Then the next code lines will be executed according to the program flow.